# Obtain parentnode with a xpath query on cakephp

Tags: php, xml, cakephp, xpath

So, i'm using Cakephp and I have a xml file that looks something like this:

```
<something>
<table id="t1">
  <columns>
    <column id="c1"/>
    <column id="c2"/>
  </columns>
</table>
<table id="t2">
  <columns>
......
</something>
```

I was using Set::extract to search for the column based on it's id, no problems with that one:

```
Set::extract("/something/table/columns/column[id=$column_id"]", $array);
```

Now i need to get the parent table of that column. I tried with Set and SimpleXMLElement, but to no avail.

Can someone help me? thanks

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short XPath solution that doen't use any reverse axis. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use**:

```
Set::extract("/something/table[columns/column[id=$column_id"]]", $array);
```

**The XPath expression**:

```
/something/table[columns/column[id=$column_id"]]
```

**selects** all `table` elements that are children of the top element `something` and that have a `columns/column` grand-child element the string value of whose `id` child is equal to the string value of the variable `$column_id`.

Comment: I don't understand much about XPath, but in theory it would probably works. It just doesn't with Set::extract
it gives me an empty array.

Comment: @peugas55: Try using SimpleXMLElement::xpath

Comment: @peugas55: I don't know PHP and the XPath engine it uses or its API. If this XPath expression "doesn't work" then your question is not about XPath but about this particular implementation of XPath.  I can provide a complete XSLT code example that confirms that the XPath expression in my answer selects the wanted element -- do you want me to do so?

Comment: Like i said, I also think that the query should work. It just doesn't when I use Set::extract. I tried with SimpleXMLElement::xpath and it finally works. The only thing is it needs to be '$column_id' instead of just $columnd_id, which should have been quite obvious.